# Running osascript after 'su -'

Tags: macos, su, osascript

I have a program run from the command line in OSX that I want to be able to pop up messages occasionally by running something like this:

```
osascript -e "display dialog \"Message\""
```

This works fine if I never change users. If I `su other_user` and run the program on the command line, it continues to work. But if I `su - other_user`, it no longer works, saying `error retrieving current process`.

How can I get `display dialog` to run even after changing users with `su -l`?

Comment: "How can I get `osacript` to run" I think you'll find that `osascript` runs just fine. It's `display dialog` that's the problem.

Comment: @matt I did see that question, but it has no answers and also there is an additional error message. Since, in my limited case, I only get the `current process` error and since I can run it after `su` but not `su -`, there might be an easier solution around in my limited case.

Comment: @matt you're right, changed question wording to reflect that. maybe i should change question title as well?

Comment: "there might be an easier solution" I don't think so. The trouble is that `display dialog` needs to appear somewhere. You're not giving it enough info to do that. You might try `tell application "Finder" to display dialog...` but I don't guarantee anything.

Comment: `display dialog` alone works both as original user and after `su` without prompting for password. If I add `tell app \"blah\" to ...`, it works for original user, requires entering password after `su` to different user, and fails with a different error after `su -`

Comment: Well, I can't say I'm surprised. :(